# Coding a group of interrelated objects which are updated upon addition or removal of an object in the group

Tags: python

So I have a group of N persons each having their own unique id. Each person has a randomized opinion of each already existing person ranging from 0 to 100. Upon the addition of a new person, I'd like all existing persons to acquire a randomized opinion of this new person. Upon removal of an existing person, I'd like all remaining persons to remove their opinion of the removed person.

Here's what I have up to now:

```
import random

persons = {}

class Person():
    def __init__(self, idn):
        self.idn = idn
        self.opinions = {}

        for i in persons:
            self.opinions[i] = random.randrange(100)

        persons[idn] = self

        for i in persons:
            persons[i].update()

    def update(self):
        pass


for i in range(20):
    person_i = Person(i)
```

Now clearly the problem here is that only the last created object has opinions of all other persons. I was tinkering with creating a Person.update() function, but I have no clue how to proceed.

I was thinking, perhaps there is already somewhere a framework created to deal with this type of situation? (I would eventually hope to make even more complicated interrelations). The idea is having an object that holds a relationship to every other object in its group, and vice-versa for each other object in the group.

Any help is appreciated, especially resources to learn. I am a beginner at python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here for your reference, it is not working for more Person groups, just one Person group. If you need more groups, you have to specified group key for each person. If you want to del person, should person.delete() first.

```py
import random

class Person():

    table = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.key = self.get_key()
        self.opinions = {}
        for key in Person.table:
            self.opinions[key] = random.randrange(100)
        for person in Person.table.values():
            person.opinions[self.key] = random.randrange(100)
        Person.table[self.key] = self

    def get_key(self):
        i = 0
        while i in Person.table:
            i += 1
        return i

    def delete(self):
        del Person.table[self.key]
        for person in Person.table.values():
            del person.opinions[self.key]
        del self

persons = [Person() for i in range(20)]
```